# Python script for shapefile to layer conversion

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python

What is the Python script for shapefile to layer conversion? I tried the following...

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
env.workspace="working path"  
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_conversion("source shapefile", "target name")
```

Comment: `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("source shapefile", "target name")`

Comment: ok, i tried that also...

Comment: Could you please post the code that isn't working? It's working on my end.

Comment: import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace="G:/gis/test"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("india.shp","indlyr")

Comment: If you are doing this outside of ArcMap, then you need to [save the layer to disk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Save_To_Layer_File/001700000070000000/)

Comment: why, is therr any strong reason?

Comment: Because it's only temporary. I'm guessing you think that it's failing because you don't see an output?

Comment: I am starting work with arcgis and i want to known if you can give a Python script for converting layers to a shapefile ? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work...

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "G:/gis/test"
dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
lyr = r'Path To output location' # e.g. r'C:\Mapping\IndiaLyr.Lyr'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(dataset, "indlyr")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("indlyr", lyr, "ABSOLUTE")
```

Edited to accomodate script tool solution.  You can probably get rid of the env.workspace variable as it won't be used.

Once you create the script tool from your script, right click the script tool and select properties.

Give your script tool a name...

[image]

Click the Parameters tab, give your input parameter a Display Name and select the data type you would like to use (if you expect to either use a shapefile, feature class, etc. use the Dataset data type)

[image]

Click finish.  Now open your script tool by double clicking it or right clicking and selecting open.  Browse or drag and drop your dataset.

[image]

Comment: +1 Quick and simple.  Although env.worksapce has a spelling error.

Comment: Now i want to make a simple  tool from the above code?I tried to add this script file in tool box but i failed to set parameters?Please Explain?

Comment: What part of the help files have you read on creating tools before we replicate information you may already be familiar with?